# designer.cs files conflicting with pre-existing .cs files converted from VS 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am in the process of recreating a bunch of webpages that were orginally created in Visual Studio 2005. I have fixed many of the issues in re-using the controls deisgned for the old pages, but I am still hitting one major snag:

The ControlName.ascx.designer.cs files are creating duplicate definitions for assorted fields that were already defined in ControlName.ascx.cs. Even excluding 75% of the old control files from the project, there is nearly 100 conflicts bewteen the designer.cs files and the control files I brought in from the old site.
Unlike the designer version of the file, the orginal actually contains a significant amount of code.
I can delete the field from the designer fiel, but that will only work until the next time it is regenerated.

Is there a way to disable generation of these files for the pre-existing controls, or is there some other solution to resolve all of these conflicts? I am still pretty new to Visual Studio.

A sample of the errors is:
Error   25  The type 'MyCompany.Web.UI.Controls.dyn_content' already contains a definition for 'rptList'    D:\projects\Portals\Portals\Portals\controls\dyn_content.ascx.designer.cs   22  62  Portals